# MVC Route Configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following in my HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Share(string id)
{
    Debate debate;
    try
    {
        debate = Db.Debates.Single(deb => deb.ShareText.Equals(id));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(debate);
}
```

This allows me to call the url this way:

`http://localhost:50499/Home/Share/SomeTextHere`

I configured the route this way in the routeconfig file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Share",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Share", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I want to be able how to call the URL this way:

`http://localhost:50499/Debate/SomeTextHere`

I have been struggling with this with no luck. What is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: You cannot remove both the controller and action name from the url. You routes need to be distinguishable in some way. You could create a route for say `.../Share/SomeTextHere`

Comment: Note also that both the routes you have shown are identical - they both match any url that contains 2 segments with an optional 3rd segment. Your 2nd route can never be hit (you may as well delete the 1st)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I changed the URL to http://localhost:50499/Debate/SomeTextHere

Is this possible?

Comment: @MRFerocius you can set that as the route and set the defaults to the controller and action you want. Where do you want that url to map to?

Comment: If you want `../Debate/SomeTextHere` then change the first route definition to `url: "Debate/{id}",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @StephenMuecke you would need to change the route to not make it so general.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Share",
        url: "Debate/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Share", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

the `Share` route would now allow `http://localhost:50499/Debate/SomeTextHere` to route to the appropriate controller action.

Comment: I think OP wants just `../Debate/xx` so its `url: "Debate/{id}",`

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are correct. I misread the requirement. Thanks